# http internal server error 500

Tags: iis-7, 500-error

complete n00b to servers and their errors.

Running a site on a windows 2008 server with IIS7 and I've gotten the internal server error 500 when I try to visit the site. It was working up until very recently. No changes were made either.

The server is a virtual server stored offsite with an outsourced company. Would this be an issue for them?

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: It might be useful to point out that if I visit the site's full URL, e.g. http://www.example.com/index.html I can see the site, same with the other site pages however some images appear broken. Some pages still however return the http 500 error.

Comment: IIS 7 gives a very detailed error on the cause of the issue. Could you pls elaborate on the kind of application you are trying to host on IIS and 'Internal Server Error' usually means something to do with configuration/functionality in IIS.

Comment: Looks like you are having 500 error for dynamic pages, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: IIRC IIS7 provides you with a sub-status-code (don't know what it's called). IIS segments the 500 Status into 500.* status'. You might want to read up here: [The HTTP Status Codes in IIS 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891/en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a web-server reports error 500 I look in the server's error log for a detailed reason.

The following look useful

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/07/26/Troubleshoot-IIS7-errors-like-a-pro.aspx

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/